# Error Reading and writing files (Java)

Tags: java, file, object, load, save

Hi guys i just implemented object files into my program and i am constantly getting the errors (error reading file and problem writing to file) these are 2 errors in my try catch block, when i try to read the file it does not load, saving doesn't work either.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Stores implements Serializable
{
    public static ArrayList<Student> stud1 = new ArrayList<Student>();
    public static ArrayList<SubjectTeacher> sTeach1 = new ArrayList<SubjectTeacher>();
    private static int iT = 0;
    private static int iS = 0;


    public static void savet (ArrayList<SubjectTeacher> teachIn, int count)
        {
            iT = count;
            sTeach1 = teachIn;
            saveTeachToFile();
        }

    public static void saves (ArrayList<Student> studIn, int count)
        {
            iS = count;
            stud1 = studIn;
            saveStudToFile();
        }

    public static ArrayList<Student> getStud ()
        {
            return stud1;
        }

    public static ArrayList<SubjectTeacher> getTeach ()
        {
            return sTeach1;
        }

    public static int getStudSize()
        {
            return stud1.size();
        }

    public static int getTeachSize()
        {
            return sTeach1.size();
        }

    private static void saveStudToFile()
    {
        try
        {
            // create a FileOutputStream object which will handles the writing of the sudent list of objects to the file.
            FileOutputStream studentFile = new FileOutputStream("Students.obf");
            // the OutputObjectStream object will allow us to write whole objects to and from files
            ObjectOutputStream studentStream = new ObjectOutputStream(studentFile);

            for(Student item: stud1)    // enhanced for loop
            // Loop through the list of studentsListIn and for each of these objects, wite them to the file
            {
                studentStream.writeObject(item);
            }
            //close the file so that it is no longer accessible to the program
            studentStream.close();
        }

        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("There was a problem writing the File");
        }
    }

    private static void saveTeachToFile()
    {
        try
        {
            FileOutputStream teacherFile = new FileOutputStream("Teacher.obf");
            ObjectOutputStream teacherStream = new ObjectOutputStream(teacherFile);

            for(SubjectTeacher item1: sTeach1)  // enhanced for loop
            {
               teacherStream.writeObject(item1);
            }
            //close the file so that it is no longer accessible to the program
            teacherStream.close();
        }

        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("There was a problem writing the File");
        }
    }

    public static void loadStudentList()
    {
        boolean endOfFile = false;
        Student tempStudent;

        try
        {
            // create a FileInputStream object, studentFile
            FileInputStream studentFile = new FileInputStream("Students.obf");
            // create am ObjectImnputStream object to wrap around studentStream
            ObjectInputStream studentStream = new ObjectInputStream(studentFile) ;

            // read the first (whole) object with the readObject method
            tempStudent = (Student) studentStream.readObject();

            while (endOfFile != true)
            {
                try
                {
                    stud1.add(tempStudent);
                    // read the next (whole) object
                    tempStudent = (Student) studentStream.readObject();
                }

                //use the fact that the readObject throws an EOFException to check whether the end of eth file has been reached
                catch(EOFException e)
                {
                    endOfFile = true;
                }

                studentStream.close();
            }
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }

        catch(ClassNotFoundException e)   // thrown by readObject
        /* which indicates that the object just read does not correspond to any class
        known to the program */
        {
            System.out.println("Trying to read an object of an unkonown class");
        }

        catch(StreamCorruptedException e)   //thrown by constructor
        // which indicates that the input stream given to it was not produced by an ObjectOutputStream object         {
        {
           System.out.println("Unreadable File Format");
        }

        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("There was a problem reading the file");
        }
    }

    public static void loadTeacherList()
    {
        boolean endOfFile = false;
        SubjectTeacher tempTeacher;

        try
        {

            FileInputStream teacherFile = new FileInputStream("Teacher.obf");

            ObjectInputStream teacherStream = new ObjectInputStream(teacherFile) ;


            tempTeacher = (SubjectTeacher) teacherStream.readObject();

            while (endOfFile != true)
            {
                try
                {
                    sTeach1.add(tempTeacher);
                    // read the next (whole) object
                    tempTeacher = (SubjectTeacher) teacherStream.readObject();
                }

                //use the fact that the readObject throws an EOFException to check whether the end of eth file has been reached
                catch(EOFException e)
                {
                    endOfFile = true;
                }

                teacherStream.close();
            }
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }

        catch(ClassNotFoundException e)   // thrown by readObject
        /* which indicates that the object just read does not correspond to any class
        known to the program */
        {
            System.out.println("Trying to read an object of an unkonown class");
        }

        catch(StreamCorruptedException e)   //thrown by constructor
        // which indicates that the input stream given to it was not produced by an ObjectOutputStream object         {
        {
           System.out.println("Unreadable File Format");
        }

        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("There was a problem reading the file");
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: I don't see a try catch block

Comment: ... or file reads/writes

Comment: What are the errors? Where do they happen? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Your code seems to have nothing to do with your question.  What exceptions are you getting?  Where are you reading/writing files?

Comment: Weird.. my `go to definition` button isn't working on here. Guess we'll just need to see the code.

Comment: I know why it isn't reading/writing files! You have to write the code to do it first! Rookie mistake.

Comment: ok sorry about the misunderstanding guys my code was not all posted i shall edit my question
sincerest apologies

Comment: Hurry, post some code! I'm running out of clever sarcasm!

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/nay5cym9zgfy7yt/z8RrbZ5Eq5/Stores.java

My code is there, i posted the wrong class, now thats a rookie mistake

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt anything :P

Comment: @MatthewCassar in the future try to post a smaller example that reproduces the problem. Dumping a lot of code in a question tends to turn people off, and you get a less help. Basically less is generally better, adding in more when asked or deemed necessary.

Comment: You should add `e.printStackTrace()` in your catch blocks so you see what the stacktraces are. Basically you are catching the error, and saying "Hey it broke" but not giving yourself enough information to know why it broke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Well, for one thing, you should edit the question with the correct code so it doesn't get closed. Second,</s> A couple of things could be happening.

1. The classes you're writing to file aren't serializable
2. The files are readonly or write protected somehow

Based on the code from your updated question, it looks like you may be confusing which classes need to implement `Serializable`. The classes that need to implement that are the ones you're actually writing to file (ie `SubjectTeacher`, etc.).

Check those two, and let me know what you find.

Also, I'd suggest stepping the code and seeing what the exceptions look like at runtime. You'll get a much better idea of what's going on.

Comment: thank you, and again sorry for the misunderstand, unfortunately that did not work

Comment: Testing it out it works :D but it still shows the error about reading the file (although it is actually being red)

Comment: @MatthewCassar what does the exception say? Look through the properties of it for the description (I forget what the property is actually called in java -- I've been writing c# code for a while)